# Javascript code after choosing a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, coffeescript

I need to execute certain piece of code after user chooses file from file input. The tricky part is I cannot check the input for it, so:

```
$('input').change ->
```

is out of the question, I need to detect user clicking "Open" button. Is it possible?

Comment: you have to check the files array from input, is it null or full

Comment: have you tried `$('input').on('click', function` ? that should detect clicking on the open button, however you wouldt have access to the selected file. can you give more details on what you need access to etc?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to check the file input's FileList.

```
<input type="file" id="file">

$('#file').on('change', function() {
  return console.log($(this)[0].files);
});
```

Worth bearing in mind that if you were to select a file and then go back in and choose the same file a second time, the function will not fire as the input hasn't truly changed.

In this scenario you'd need to set a flag somewhere that resets when you click the input (or something similar).